# I am getting get_ipython().magic Error for using time function

Tags: python, numpy, ipython, jit

I am trying to time a simple matrix multiplication program using numpy and Numba.
Here is my code

The error I am getting is `get_ipython().magic('time _ = A.dot(B)') SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

```py
import time
import numpy as np
from numba import jit, njit, vectorized

A = np.random.randint(0, 15, size=(1000,1000))
B = np.random.randint(0, 15, size=(1000,1000))

%time A.dot(B)

@jit(nopython=True)
%time _ = A.dot(B)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think are a few misconceptions you are making, and resolving those will make your code work as well.

1. The `%time` is a [line magic](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html) from IPython.
   This does not require a import of the `time` python package.
2. Decorators (like your `@jit(nopython=True)` expression) are there to wrap function or class definitions. Putting them in front of regular lines of code would give you the same error.
   What you can do to make this code workable in your situation is to wrap the line of code you are trying to process in a function.

A working version of your code would be something like this:

```py
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

A = np.random.randint(0, 15, size=(1000,1000))
B = np.random.randint(0, 15, size=(1000,1000))

%time A.dot(B)

@jit(nopython=True)
def wrapped_dot(A, B):
  return A.dot(B)

%time _ = wrapped_dot(A, B)
```

Though I would also remark that since you are already working with numpy arrays,  numba is probably not going to achieve a noticeable speedup, since numpy is already optimized.

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried implementing your corrects and I got this error:         TypingError: Failed in nopython mode pipeline (step: nopython frontend)
- Resolution failure for literal arguments:

Comment: I tried it out as well. It seems, to use the numpy `dot` method, the arrays can't be ints, have to be floats or complex numbers, and you need to have scipy installed for it to work at all